# Changing from info.cukes to io.cucumber with testNG Maven. Throwing runtime error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

I have a selenium cucumber testng framework using maven. I was hoping to get step descriptions when I run my cucumber tests with testng. It was an old project so I have changed my dependencies from info.cukes to the latest version of io.cucumber. However it seems to be throwing out errors whenever I run the runner test file.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.getPluginFormatterNames()Ljava/util/List;

    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins.createPlugins(Plugins.java:64)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:37)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:56)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

I have the following maven dependencies but have no idea if it is a dependency that I am missing to get the test to run? Any Help would be greatly appreciated. As when I have search this issue it seems that it is mostly solved by having the same version dependencies of all the io.cucumber files which I do.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>

</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/tag-expressions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>tag-expressions</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-expressions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-expressions</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/messages -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>messages</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mkolisnyk/cucumber-report-generator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.14</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>



     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.sbtqa.tag/cucumber-runner -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.sbtqa.tag</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below some snippets to break down the problem

1. check if there is a [transitive dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) to groupid `info.cukes`

   ```
   $ mvn dependency:tree | grep 'info.cuke'
   [INFO] |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:compile
   [INFO] |  |  \- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
   [INFO] |  |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:compile
   [INFO] |  |     \- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.5:compile
   [INFO] |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-testng:jar:1.2.5:compile
   [INFO]    |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:compile
   [INFO]    |  +- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:compile
   ```

   when checking the full output reveals which of your dependency depends on it

   ```
   ...
   [INFO] +- com.github.mkolisnyk:cucumber-report-generator:jar:1.3:compile
   ...
   [INFO] |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:compile
   ...
   [INFO] |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-testng:jar:1.2.5:compile
   ...
   [INFO] \- ru.sbtqa.tag:cucumber-runner:jar:1.0.7:compile
   [INFO] \- ru.sbtqa.tag:cucumber-runner:jar:1.0.7:compile
   [INFO]    +- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor:jar:1.6.4:compile
   ...
   [INFO]    |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
   ...
   [INFO]    |  +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:compile
   [INFO]    |  +- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:compile
   ...
   [INFO]    +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:compile
   ```
2. as there might be an overlapping of classed with the same qualified name, exclude those transient dependencies in the `pom.xml`

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
           <artifactId>cucumber-report-generator</artifactId>
           <version>1.3</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                   <artifactId>*</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
   ```
3. running the test again it throws an exception

   ```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider
   ```
4. as we explicitly define the dependency `io.cucumber:gherkin` it might be related to the specified `<version>`, comment it out to see if another version is fetched

   ```
   <!--<dependency>-->
       <!--<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>-->
       <!--<artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>-->
       <!--<version>6.0.14</version>-->
   <!--</dependency>-->
   ```

   this reveals that `io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:4.2.0` depends on version `5.1.0` of `io.cucumber:gherkin`

   ```
   $ mvn dependency:tree
   ...
   [INFO] +- io.cucumber:cucumber-core:jar:4.2.0:compile
   [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.7:compile
   [INFO] |  +- io.cucumber:gherkin:jar:5.1.0:compile
   ```

With those changes at least the `TestNG` unit test is running.

As the dependencies `com.github.mkolisnyk:cucumber-report-generator` and `ru.sbtqa.tag:cucumber-runner` depending on the `info.cuke` dependencies they might not work correctly anymore. To solve this kind of problem you could:

- check for a newer version which might not depend on group id `info.cuke`
- use earlier version of `io.cucumber` dependencies
- use a more finegrained exclusion of the `info.cuke` dependencies, instead of excluding all artifact ids
- a combination of above points
- something else, depending on your use case and requirements

Maybe those steps help you to find a solution working for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your incredibly detailed reply!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your incredibly detailed reply!! I am a little confused as to why in step 1 we are looking at the dependency of group id info.cukes if I am instead trying to use io.cucumber? I believe that that io.cucumber is the latest version of info.cuke as they changed their group id and continued developpment there. At Step 4 if I am understanding correctly because io.gherkin is a dependency of io.cucumber core then maven takes care of it and fetches it for me? So there is no need for that to be included in my code. Is that correct?

Comment: @M.Waddelow to 1) You're right that groupid `info.cukes` is the predecessor of `io.cucumber`. In such a case the chance that classes kept their qualified name is quite high. As you want to use the classes from `io.cucumber` we should check for transient dependencies of `info.cuke`. As Maven can't handle this kind of dependency "version" update for you. to 2) If dependencies define multiple versions for the same `groupid:artifactid` by default Maven uses the highest version.

Answer (score 2):

Check maven pom.xml cucumber-core cucumber-java cucumber-junit

These files should have the same version. In your example, cucumber-java artifact id has a different version than the rest.

Try changing it.

Comment: Are you sure? Above I see: cucumber-java:4.2.0, cucumber-core:4.2.0, cucumber-junit: 4.2.0 and cucumber-testng: 4.2.0